# Conditionally move rows into another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets one called Details and another called Reconciled. I have 1000+ rows in Details and I want to cut all rows that have 0 or a - in column E (I want to cut the entire row) and paste it into sheet Details. If possible I would like to copy and paste the headers from Reconciled into Details as well.

I've tried using this code (modified slightly) used in another post

```
Sub Test()
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Details").Range("E:E")
        If Cell.Value = "0" Then
            matchRow = Cell.Row
            Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
            Selection.Copy

            Sheets("Reconcile").Select
            ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Details").Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But there are 2 problems. Because some values - (numbers are truly) those get moved, but the ones that are 0.00 do not get moved because they are rounded (I think that's why they are not being moved). Also, the screen updates oddly, and I'm sorry I can't explain it more than.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: for a faster and cleaner (and probably) less problematic approach, use the `.AutoFilter` method to get the data you want to filter on, then use the '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method to copy the filtered rows to the other sheet. For the screen flickering, used `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the code, then set it to `True` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Sub Test()
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       On Error Goto Finish
       For Each Cell In Sheets("Details").Range("E:E")
          If Cell.Value = 0 Or Cell.Value = "-" Then cell.EntireRow.copy Sheets("Reconcile").Rows(cell.Row)
       Next
Finish:
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Notice: dont put quotes around the 0, this will make numeric comparison

Answer (score 0):

Using Autofilter:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Details").UsedRange
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0"

        .Copy
        With Worksheets("Reconciled").Cells(1, 1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .Parent.Activate:   .Select
        End With

        .Rows(1).Hidden = True
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .Rows(1).Hidden = False
        .AutoFilter
        .Parent.Activate
        .Cells(1, 1).Activate
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```